# Round half even for double

Tags: java, rounding

I need to round to nearest 0.5 if possible.

10.4999 = 10.5

Here is quick code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

public class DecimalFormat  
{  
   public static void main(String[] args)  
   {  
      DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
      dFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

      final double test = 10.4999;

      System.out.println("Format: " + dFormat.format(test));
   }  
}
```

This doesn't work because 6.10000... rounds to 6.1 etc...need it to round to 6.0

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: so, did you try something different? Come on, can't be so hard..

Comment: `Round.HALF_EVEN` has nothing at all to do with your requirement.

Comment: 2.6000000 is the same value as 2.6, no rounding has occurred

Comment: sorry edited, sleepy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than try rounding to the nearest 0.5, double it, round to the nearest int, then  divide by two.

This way, 2.49 becomes 4.98, rounds to 5, becomes 2.5.
2.24 becomes 4.48, rounds to 4, becomes 2.

Comment: It's things like this that make programming go so well with mathematics. +1

Comment: Actually, there is no need to double it. Just doing - `(int)d + 0.5;` will work fine.

Comment: @RohitJain `(int)d + 0.5` changes 6.1 to 6.5, which is not what he wants

Comment: @RobWatts. OOPs. Missed the last line in question.

Comment: its not about a mathematical route, its that I was under the impression the HALF_EVEN rounding mode was to do exactly that.

Comment: @lcplusplus see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) for an explanation of HALF_EVEN

Comment: `Math.rint` is the way to do HALF_EVEN rounding for `double`.

Comment: This is wrong. What happens with 2.25? Same difference.

Comment: @user511287 How is it wrong? 2.25 becomes 4.5, rounds to 5, becomes 2.5. That's what should be happening.

Answer (score 8):

A more general solution to @RobWatt's answer in case you ever want to round to something else:

```
private static double roundTo(double v, double r) {
  return Math.round(v / r) * r;
}

System.out.println(roundTo(6.1, 0.5));     // 6.0
System.out.println(roundTo(10.4999, 0.5)); // 10.5
System.out.println(roundTo(1.33, 0.25));   // 1.25
System.out.println(roundTo(1.44, 0.125));  // 1.5
```

Comment: I like this, though I would suggest changing `r` to mean the reciprocal of whatever you're trying to round to. The calculation would then be `Math.round(v * r) / r;`. Doing it that way would make it easier to round to the nearest third, or other fractions that have a messy decimal representation.

Comment: @RobWatts True, though, the point of rounding is usually to avoid messy decimals. I generally use this method for rounding large numbers (e.g. `roundTo(9788699.4324, 1000) // 9789000.0`)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DecimalFormat  
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        double test = 10.4999;

        double round;
        int i = (int) test;
        double fraction = test - i;
        if (fraction < 0.25) {
            round = (double) i;
        } else if (fraction < 0.75) {
            round = (double) (i + 0.5);
        } else {
            round = (double) (i + 1);
        }
        System.out.println("Format: " + round);
    }  
}
```

Comment: @user511287 - 2.25 outputs: `Format: 2.5`. What's wrong with it?