# Round double with .5 and above to the ceil value

Tags: java, android, math

I'm having some issues with rounding up values to intergers. In my app I have this values `250/6=41.6667`. and or this i get the value of 41 instead of 42. Can anyone tell me how can I round up this value to the ceiling?

Here is what I do now:

```
 public BigDecimal roundToHalf(double d) {
            BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(d);
            value = value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
            Log.d(TAG, "youcan val =" + value);
            return value;
    }
/////////
    int nowYouPay = 250;
    int billSize= billTotals.size();// value of 6

    int res =roundToHalf(nowYouPay / billSize);//this retunrs 41
```

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221381/round-half-even-for-double)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer division: result is already "rounded down" when you divide nowYouPay / billSize.
So you are actually calling roundToHalf(41) instead of roundToHalf(41.666..).

If you don't want the result of division to be 41, you have to use division with at least one floating point argument:

```
((double) nowYouPay)/ billSize  // 41.6666...
nowYouPay / ((double) billSize) // 41.6666...
250.0 / 6                       // 41.6666...
250 / 6.0                       // 41.6666...
250.0 / 6.0                     // 41.6666...
250 / 6                         // 41
```

Comment: `roundToHalf((double) (nowYouPay / billTotals.size()));` returns `41`

Comment: Look at the parantheses. Now tou divide nowYouPay by billTotals.size and then cast it to double. But it's already 41 after division, so it turns into 41.0. @DarkoPetkovski

Answer (score 1):

You should use `int res = Math.round(((float)nowYouPay)/billSize)`

Comment: the answer is about ceiling, not rounding

Comment: Round double with **.5 and above** to the ceil value

Comment: sorry the OP's wording is unclear and I thought that it's ceil

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public static double roundToHalf(double d) {
         return Math.ceil(d);
 }
```

or use this:

```
 public static double roundToHalf(double d) {
         return Math.round(d);
 }
```

Is more appropriate, approximates your integer 41.6667 to 42 , that is, with values ​​higher than 0.50 higher integer , otherwise the lowest

with input 41.6667 result:

> 42.0

check this: [Math Ceil](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_ceil.htm)

and [Math Round](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_round.htm)